# Efficient way to enabled or disabled multiple checkboxes with JavaScript than listing all of them?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there was a better way to go about enabled/disabled multiple checkboxes at once.
In the html I have two radio buttons to choose between all hair options and custom hair options, having the default all one disable the checkboxes while the custom one enables them. 
This is what I've got so far that *works* (probably looks dumb, I apologize), but I'd like to know if there's a more efficient way to go about this? I'd like to do it as "small" as possible while still being easily readable/understandable for my own sake.

```js
function checkHaOp(){
    if (document.getElementById("hairOptionAll").checked){
        document.getElementById("hairAuburn").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("hairBlack").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("hairBlonde").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("hairBrown").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("hairRed").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("hairOther").disabled = true;
    } 
    else if (document.getElementById("hairOptionCustom").checked){
        document.getElementById("hairAuburn").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("hairBlack").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("hairBlonde").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("hairBrown").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("hairRed").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("hairOther").disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Preferably using javascript since I don't know jquery. 
I'd also appreciate explanations of things since I am still learning.

Comment: Add a `class=".."` then do `getElementsByClassName("..").forEach(...)`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol HTMLCollections don't have forEach, you'd need qSA or `for` instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance Whoops, quite right. `querySelectorAll(".class_name_here").forEach(...)`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I couldn't get it to work, but it was probably my fault/me being dumb & in kinda a rush. I heavily considered picking yours just because of the explanations, they were very good and helpful and I really appreciate them. I'll revist this particular chunk of code after I finish v1 of my project, if/when I can figure out how to get yours working I'll change the best answer over to yours, I did like it better, but the other one worked on first try, so I picked it for now.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Yea, I saw, worked for me in the snippet too, so it was prolly me messing up something. Oh jeez, well okie dokie, if that's what you wanna do. I woulda figured it best to leave up in case somebody else had a similar issue as me and wanted options/explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add/use class like said @NiettheDarkAbsol
then something like that.

```
var inpck = document.getElementsByClassName("input-checkbox");
if (document.getElementById("hairOptionAll").checked) {
    for(var i = 0; i < inpck.length; i++) {
       inpck[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
if (document.getElementById("hairOptionCustom").checked) {
    for(var i = 0; i < inpck.length; i++) {
       inpck[i].disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Now your turn to refactor this :D

Comment: Only one loop is necessary: `let isChecked = document.getElementById("hairOptionCustom").checked;` then loop over the collection: `inpck[i].disabled = isChecked`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^=hair]')
```

It selects all elements that has an id which starts with "hair"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" id="hairOptionAll">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hairAuburn">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hairBlack">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hairBlonde">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hairBrown">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hairRed">
        <input type="checkbox" id="hairOther">
    </body>

    <script>
        const hairCb = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=hair]');
        for (let i=0; i<hairCb.length; i++) {
            hairCb[i].disabled = true;
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the optimized solution.

```html
<div class="radio-btns">
    All <input type="radio" id="hairOptionAll" name="hairOptionAll"/>
    Custom <input type="radio" id="hairOptionCustom" name="hairOptionCustom"/>
</div>
<div class="hairOptions">
    hairAuburn <input type="checkbox" id="hairAuburn" />
    hairBlack <input type="checkbox" id="hairBlack" />
    hairBlonde <input type="checkbox" id="hairBlonde" />
    hairBrown <input type="checkbox" id="hairBrown" />
    hairRed <input type="checkbox" id="hairRed" />
    hairOther <input type="checkbox" id="hairOther" />
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
        const radioBtns = document.querySelector('.radio-btns');
        radioBtns.children[0].checked = true;

        radioBtns.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            radioBtns.children[0].checked = (event.target.id == 'hairOptionAll') ? true : false;
            radioBtns.children[1].checked = (event.target.id == 'hairOptionCustom') ? true : false;

        const allOptions = [...event.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.children];
        allOptions.map(option => ( option.checked = (event.target.id == 'hairOptionCustom') ? true : false ) );
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete working code you. To minimise the `code` we write to we need to use a `class` selector not an `id` - Give the same `class` to your radio button and then use a `forEach` loop to go through all the radio `button`. Add the class to your checkboxes as well.

To get all the checkboxes we can use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method.

Once you have all the radio button you need to listen for a `change` on a particular `radio` button and then we will check whether the `radio` button we have selected is checked and its `id` is `all` or `custom`.

To get the `id` of the actual `radio` button which was clicked we can use [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method which return the id of checked radio button.

If our condition matches we will disable all the `checkboxes` or if its else then we enable all the `checkboxes` using `forEach` loop on the checkbox classes.

We will pass `true` or `false` as an argument to disable `checkboxes` function to avoid having have two `loops`

**Live Working Example** (I have added notes / comment on each line of code for your understanding as well)

```js
//Enable disable checkbox
function disableChekbox(isChecked) {
  let getHairOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.hairOptions') //get all checkboxes
  getHairOptions.forEach(function(x) {
    x.disabled = isChecked
  })
}

let getHairRadio = document.querySelectorAll('.hairOptionAll') //get all radio buttons

//For each all radio buttons
getHairRadio.forEach(function(radio) {
  //listen to change on radio
  radio.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    if (e.target.checked && e.target.getAttribute('id') == 'hairOptionAll') {
      //loop through all checkboxes
      disableChekbox(true)
    } else if (e.target.checked && e.target.getAttribute('id') == 'hairOptionCustom') {
      //loop through all checkboxes
      disableChekbox(false)
    }
  })
})
```

```html
All <input type="radio" id="hairOptionAll" name="hairOptionAll" class="hairOptionAll" />

Custom <input type="radio" id="hairOptionCustom" name="hairOptionAll" class="hairOptionAll" />
<br>
<br>
hairAuburn <input type="checkbox" id="hairAuburn" class="hairOptions" />
hairBlack <input type="checkbox" id="hairBlack" class="hairOptions" />
hairBlonde <input type="checkbox" id="hairBlonde" class="hairOptions" />
hairBrown <input type="checkbox" id="hairBrown" class="hairOptions" />

hairRed <input type="checkbox" id="hairRed" class="hairOptions" />
hairOther <input type="checkbox" id="hairOther" class="hairOptions" />
```